# PHP MYSQL order lists by popularity

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

I was wondering how I can sort the content in a ordered list set up using html. 
I need to use PHP and mySQL so any tips in this direction will be looked at seriously.

The **html** for the list

```
<div id="right-column-sidebar">
<ol>
<li><a href="#">Title 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 7</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 8</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 9</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 10</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 11</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 12</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 13</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 14</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 15</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 16</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 17</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 18</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 19</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Title 20</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

All of these titles belong to one and the same Category. All tips are welcome!

Comment: "any tips in this direction will be looked at seriously" Good to know

Comment: are the titles retrieved from database?

Comment: What's the problem ? What do you want ? Where does the data come from ? How does your php/sql look like ?

Comment: The sorting has to be done based on number of views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="right-column-sidebar">
<ol>
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
    mysql_select_db("db", $link);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) :
        ?>
        <li> <a href="#"> <?php echo $row['title']; ?> </a></li>
    <?php endwhile; 
?>
</ol>
</div>
```

This all assumes you have some data inside the database `db` and inside the table `table` you have a column called `title` which contains a bunch of entries with titles.  This will loop through the results and display them.

Of course sorting the information just requires some extra info in your query.

Comment: Is this based on how many views the different list items have had?

Comment: It depends how you store the information about views.  If each time a user on your website clicks a view, you increment a value in your table storing the information about these views, then you can simply add a `ORDER BY 'views' ASC` at the end of your $query to sort them by the number of views they have.

Comment: Please do not suggest people use `mysql_query`. It is inherently hazardous and can lead to severe harm. Use `mysqli` or PDO even in simple examples.